# Loop, subset and putting it all together - R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have a data frame. Let's call him `dean_data`

```
dean_data<-data.frame(date=c("23/06/2010", "23/06/2010", "23/06/2010", "29/07/2010", "29/07/2010", "29/07/2010"),
                  hb=c(60, 55, 50, 80, 60, 70),
                  pe=c(11.5, 11.2, 11.7, 8.5, 8, 8.25),
                  v.d=c(2.17, 2.65, 3.66, 2.78, 2.71, 2.68))
```

First, I would like to calculate the mean and sd of a parameter "n" times, changing the position of the lines by date (factor).

I can only do this if before I do the subset of data, like this:

```
jun13<-subset(dean_data, date=="23/06/2010")

B = 1000
df<-matrix(NA,nrow=B)  
for (b in (1:B)){
  df[b]<-mean(sample(jun13$hb, replace=F)/(sample(jun13$pe, replace=F)*sample(jun13$v.d, replace=F)))
}
df
```

But I have several dates (n = 30) ... I would like to learn to do this in an automatic way, subset data into groups and apply the repetition of the parameter calculation. I expected as a result a table with mean and SD by date.

Comment: What is our expected output?

Comment: So you want to group your data by date. Then perform 1000 operations on each of those groups. A result will be a data.frame with as many thousands of rows as there are unique dates. Do I get it right?

Comment: Yes! Or the 1000 results side by side in columns named by dates, or mean and SD by date. Whatever.

Answer (score 0):

So here is one attempt:

```
dat = data_frame(date=c("23/06/2010", "23/06/2010", "23/06/2010", 
                        "29/07/2010", "29/07/2010", "29/07/2010"), 
                 hb=c(60, 55, 50, 80, 60, 70), 
                 pe=c(11.5, 11.2, 11.7, 8.5, 8, 8.25), 
                 v.d=c(2.17, 2.65, 3.66, 2.78, 2.71, 2.68))

dl = split(dat, dat$date) # split the data into groups, based on date

# create a helper function for readability
find_mean = function(hb, pe, v.d) {
    sapply(1:1000, function(n) {
        x = sample(hb, replace=F)
        y = sample(pe, replace=F)
        z = sample(v.d, replace=F)
        mean(x / (y * z))
    })
}

# loop through each subset of the data and find the mean
# output is a list of 1000x1 vectors
m = lapply(dl, function(df) {
  find_mean(df$hb, df$pe, df$v.d)
})

# convert the list to a dataframe 
df = as.data.frame(m)
names(df) = names(dl)

head(df)

  23/06/2010 29/07/2010
1   1.760103   3.116560
2   1.770163   3.117997
3   1.767054   3.108493
4   1.784863   3.131723
5   1.799818   3.107862
6   1.770163   3.128762
```

Comment: The results are strange, the function are wrong in mean(x / y * z)... The correct form is mean(x / (y *z)).

Comment: I corrected the formula. Can you please explain what you mean by the results are strange? Was it just that the formula was wrong?

Comment: Yes, just this. The results not change? I expect values range 0-13.. So so.

Comment: Ah, good point. I should probably update the `head(df)` results after changing the formula. Updating now.